# Problems with Django + mod-wsgi + psycopg2

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi, psycopg2

So I am trying to make Django running with mod-wsgi for the first time. I have configured Apache as shown in examples and I am pretty sure I did everything right.

I did not set the `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` variable so it uses the default: `/var/www/.python-eggs`. I have created this directory and made it writeable for user `www-data`.

When I open the site it shows the output from `500.html` template and here's what I get in log:

```
   ...
   File "/usr/local/.../parts/django/django/db/__init__.py", line 17, in load_backend
     return import_module('.base', 'django.db.backends.%s' % backend_name)
   File "/usr/local/.../parts/django/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
     __import__(name)
   File "/usr/local/.../parts/django/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 22, in <module>
     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
 ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: cannot import name tz
```

Here's what I have in `/var/www/.python-eggs/`

```
# ls -la /var/www/.python-eggs/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 27 04:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root     4096 Jan 27 04:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 27 04:19 psycopg2-2.0.13-py2.5-linux-i686.egg-tmp

# ls -la /var/www/.python-eggs/psycopg2-2.0.13-py2.5-linux-i686.egg-tmp/psycopg2/
total 368
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 27 04:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 27 04:19 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 363318 Jan 22 03:44 _psycopg.so
```

The only file in psycopg2 egg directory is `_psycopg.so`. There's no `tz.py` file and I think this is the problem.

Please advice.

P.S., I use buildout and `djangorecipe` to deploy Django. I run buildout script with `buildout` user. Not sure if it makes sense though.

P.P.S, `psycopg2` is installed correctly because I am able to run `syncdb`.

Comment: What happens when you use the interpreter and do "from psycopg2 import tz"?

Comment: Everything works fine if I do "from psycopg2 import tz" from interpreter. As I said I am able to run syncdb, so psycopg2 is installed correctly.

Comment: try setting os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp' in django.wsgi and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Setting os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp' doesn't help, the result is the same. I see that directory /tmp/psycopg2-2.0.13-py2.5-linux-i686.egg-tmp/psycopg2/ is created with only one file _psycopg.so (no tz.py)

Comment: Why would you be looking for a file called tz.py when you know you can already import successfully from the interpreter?

What happens if you chmod to 7777, so that everyone and their dog can potentially execute and write to the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution. I have used the system python for buildout and it already had psycopg2 in site-packages. It seems there was some kind of conflict between psycopg2 in system site-packages and the one installed by buildout. I have set up a virtual python environment and used it for buildout. And this helped! No more import errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that if you're able to import it from the command line, then somewhere up the path, the www-data user is being forbidden access to the egg path.